# Capturing strings with accented characters into an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, autocomplete, user-input, non-ascii-characters

My concern is : when the user begins writing some characters into an  AutoCompleteTextView edit field, I would like that, even if he enters the equivalent un-accented characters, the actv drop down list shows him the 'real and normal' characters-accented string, for him to be able to select it.

For example, when he enters the first letters of : "Treguier" or "Hede", the drop down list associated to the autocomplete textview shows : "Tréguier" (and not Treguier) or "Hédé" (not Hede) which are the correct writings but which the user never types because he may not be aware nor willing make use of the exact writing.

Merci par avance de vos suggestions.

By the way, I have no solution to this problem. When the user enter "Tre..", the the drop down list diappears, returning nothing. Maybe there exists a specific parametrization of the atcv call (specific input method ?), but I could find nothing about that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The list (appears into the drop down list) :        

Trélivan
Trémaouézan 
Trémargat
Tremblay
Trémeheuc

Comment: Finally, I think that I will add the un-accented forms to the exiting drop down list... 
Trelivan Tremaouezan Tremargat Tremeheuc will be added to 
Trélivan Trémaouézan Trémargat Tremblay Trémeheuc
Not very elegant but will do the job I think !